# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: require.e is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

When first loading up my page(in dev mode) this error occurs

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> TypeError: require.e is not a function

```
   8 | import {VideoType} from "../../component/VideoPlayer/Types";
   9 | 
> 10 | const Location = dynamic(() => import('../../component/Location').then((comp) => comp.Location), {
     |                           ^
  11 | ssr: false,
  12 | })
```

This issue goes away after the 2nd reload
How do I get around this issue? Thanks for assisting

Comment: Got the same issue. Have you been able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I learned later that the import() function returns a promise and in production server it can (and does) fail. (I hope that someone else approves or correct this if I am mistaken)

So you can actually Alert to user failure and try to handle and catch the error .

This [article](https://sammorrowdrums.com/working-with-reacts-lazy-in-production) helped in my case